# How long does it take to learn German at a B1 level?

Tags: multiple-languages, german, germanic-languages

I speak Hungarian and learnt English as a second language (both are at a C1/C2 level) and recently developed an interest in German. I tried to find out roughly how long it would take to learn German at a B1 level but the only thing I found were ads for courses. Could someone please tell me roughly how long it would take to teach myself German with 2 hours of self-study a day? Also what good free resources are out there?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Your question appears to lack a bit of precision and this makes it difficult to come up with an answer. (1) Are you a native speaker of a Germanic language (English?)? (2) B1 and B2 are different enough to justify separate questions. Which of these are you interested in? (3) Two hours of studying (on your own?) is also rather vague, since it is unclear how you study and how much time you dedicate to each skill that is covered by CEFR. Could you please edit your question to make it more specific?

Answer (score -1):

The [Youlden twins](https://www.superpolyglotbros.com), who speak 20 languages, claim that you can learn a language in [seven](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/turkish-challenge) or even [five](https://www.prosieben.de/tv/galileo/videos/201758-kann-man-eine-sprache-in-5-tagen-lernen-clip) days. Michael speaks 30 languages and learned Hindi at an advanced level in [four weeks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_hXODDU4cA). The average person doesn't even speak their native tongue correctly. So anything between 5 days and never seems possible.

How long *you* would take to learn German at a B1 level is impossible to predict. My best guess would be to assume that learning German will take you equally long as learning English.